# convert number into money format(Indian System) in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a question about formatting the Rupee currency (Indian Rupee - INR).

For example, numbers here are represented as:

```
1
10
100
1,000
10,000
1,00,000
10,00,000
1,00,00,000
10,00,00,000
```

How can i make that possible in postgresql?

i tried this code but not working perfectly `SELECT rtrim(to_char (100000,'99,99,99,99,999,9D99'));`

it returns like this `10,000,0.00`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select to_char(100000, 'FM99,999,9D00') -- o/p 10,000,0.00
select to_char(100000, 'FM9,99,999D00') -- o/p 1,00,000.00
```

100000 is your input value so

```
9, 99, 999 D 00
^   ^   ^  ^ ^
1, 00, 000 . 00
```

[`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-EXAMPLES-TABLE) // [`Demo`](http://rextester.com/GLRS27367)

- `D` specifies decimal
- `FM`  removes leading and trailing whitespace
- `9`  value with the specified number of digits([`Numeric formatting`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-NUMERIC-TABLE)), for the above example it should be 6 nos

Comment: but it will return `10,000,0.00` i want `1,00,000.00`

Comment: Here you go  - `select to_char(100000, 'FM9,99,999D00')`

Comment: it working for `100000` but when i change the number to `1000000` it returns `#` only. also i need to check `1 core` and above`(10000000)`

Comment: You missed this `9 - value with the specified number of digits(Numeric formatting), for the above example it should be 6 nos`

Comment: @ wingedpanther thnx... i got it, This is the final answer `select to_char(100000000, 'FM99,FM99,99,999D00')` it work perfectly for all numbers i asked in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_char(100000000, 'FM99,FM99,99,999D00')
```

it working perfectly for any numbers(indian money format)

```
1,000
10,000
1,00,000
10,00,000
1,00,00,000
10,00,00,000
```

Comment: Not any number, limited to `100000000`(9 digits) only// http://rextester.com/HGGXY38927

Comment: ` to_char(1000000000, 'FM99,FM99,FM99,99,999D00')` i think this may solve that issue. i added `FM99` three times

Comment: Obviously it should